# Ошибка сервера 500. Как исправить?

Tags: http-status-code-500

Люди добрые, скажите пожалуйста, что означает эта ошибка:

> [Tue Dec 04 12:57:14.452101 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 796] [client
>   62.244.4.150:49616] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/ditstest/data/www/ditstest.php-academy.org/webroot/stories/:
>   No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and
>   server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

и как её исправить?

Answer (score 0):

В директории /var/www/ditstest/data/www/ditstest.php-academy.org/webroot/stories/ нет файлов index.php,index.html

Веб-сервер пытается прочитать и показать эти файлы, но не находит их указанной директории

Comment: Дело в том, что я добавляю новый раздел на сайт и при попытке перейти в этот раздел белый экран, а в логах апача вот эта ошибка. Остальные разделы нормально работают. В директорию webroot/stories/  я ничего не добавлял. Там и не должно быть файлов index, только фото

Comment: Значит ссылка на ваш новый раздел равна /stories. При попытке перейти по такой ссылке веб сервер пытается считать каталог с таким именем и внутри инего ищет файлы index.php, index.html. И не находит их